# Systems of equations with matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

This question is about reduced row echelon form, Gauss-Jordan, inverting matrices, and solving systems of equations.

I try to solve a system of equations with matrices. I know what operations are allowed, but I just seem to arrive at the wrong conclusion 50 % of the times. So here are three problems, each with my calculation. My hope is to clarify if I:

- am making a careless misstake, and where those mistakes are (if so, I may have to do these problems in a slower pace)
- do not know the theory well enough (don't make the correct steps)
- use a bad or "not smart" way of attacking the problem. (for example, if I do *row1 + row2* when I shoul have taken *row1 - row3*).

## problem 1

problem: see picture.

solution: see picture.

[image: pb1]

## problem 2

problem: see picture.

solution: see picture.

[image: pb2.1]

[image: pb2.2]

## problem 3

problem:
[image]

solution: see picture below.

I say $x_3=-\frac{1}{a^2-2}$ while the book says $x_3=-a^2-2$

[image: pb3]

Comment: Jacob: you need to start considering *accepting* and *upvoting* answers to your questions. You can accept exactly *one* answer per post, and you can do this by clicking on the grey $\large\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you want to accept. It turns green when you click on it, and you get two reputation points. You can *upvote* as many answers as you'd like, and you can do this by clicking on the grey "uparrow" $\uparrow$ to the left of the answer you're upvoting. It turns red when you click on it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand the rules of row echelon form and reduced row echelon form before tackling these problems.
First we need a leading one on the top left corner. 
Then the leading one must go down and shift to the right
If applicable, a row of zeros on the bottom of the matrix.

For reduce row echelon form all of these rules apply along with this one: the leading one must have 0's on the top and bottom of the column.

Now there are three row operations:
switching the rows
multiplying a row with a number
adding two rows and use the new result to replace the old row 
The main diagonal is on a11, a22, and a33 .
I like to draw triangles as a border line. For row echelon form, you need and upper triangular matrix. Therefore, the numbers that are below the main diagonal need to be turned to zero.

Comment: For the second row operation, make sure the number by which you multiply isn't zero.

Comment: I believe I have reduced them so that the triangle is full of zeroes. Maybe not in the regular way, but still, with the same operations I should have the right answer.